# (Python) Error with printing a specific item from a list, based on user input?

Tags: python, list, printing, element, user-input

I have a list of years (ranging from 2023 to 1956), and another list of numbers corresponding to each year (2023 -> 1, 2022 -> 5, etc). What I want to do is ask the user to input a certain year, then print the number corresponding to that year.
I used a piece of code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768062/how-to-print-specific-parts-of-a-list-using-user-input-in-python), slightly adjusted to fit the lists and data that I have;

```
inputyear = input("Data?")
for i in range (len(host)):
    if host[i][0] == inputyear: 
     print(inputyear, str(host[i]))
```

("host" is the list of numbers, btw)

However, when I run this, I get an error stating that "'int' object is not callable," even though neither `inputyear` nor `input` are (as far as I can tell) integers, and the code seemed to work for the people in aforementioned question thread.

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Maybe `range` or `len` or `print` or `str` is an integer?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here_ It seems that you have defined your own variable called `input`, or `range`, or `len`, or `print`, or `str`.  Don't do that, because it overwrites the built-in function of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the noted issue link and making an assumption about the structure of your "host" list (aka using some artistic license), following is a refactored version of your code with a subset list which seemed to provide the desired output.

```
host = [('2023', '1'), ('2022', '5')]   # Assumed structure of list

inputyear = input("Data? ")

for i in range (len(host)):
    if host[i][0] == inputyear: 
     print(inputyear, str(host[i][1]))  # Added second element
```

The key elements are the structure of the list which is a "year/number" pair and the addition of selecting the second data element within the "str" call.

Following was the terminal output of a quick test referencing the year "2022".

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Year$ python3 Search.py 
Data? 2022
2022 5
```

See if that addresses your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the [1] to str(host[i]) inside print

```
print(inputyear, str(host[i][1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a better answer, it would be good to know more details. For example how does `host` look like?

The SO question you linked is different, because the list there contains tuples, so one can access elements in the tuple with for example `[0]`.

Judging from what you described your list `host` contains integers corresponding to the year. To fix you problem you can therefore just leave out `[0]`:

```
for i in range (len(host)):
    if host[i] == inputyear: 
     print(inputyear, str(host[i]))
```

I assume `inputyear` will be an integer variable corresponding to a year (e.g. 2).

However a more 'pythonian' way would be to solve it by doing this:

```
matching_years = [year for year in host if year == inputyear]
for matching_year in matching_years:
    print(inputyear, str(matching_year))
```

Which is faster (you can decide if this important for you).

**EDIT:** Juding from *@NoDakker*´s answer I might have understood your question wrong. So please provide more details if you want to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to do is ask the user to input a certain year, then print the number corresponding to that year. ..."*

Utilize a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Here is an example.

```java
x, y, z = int(input()), 0, 0
d = {k: (z := z + 1) for k in range(1956, 2024)}
for k, v in d.items():
    if v == x:
        y = k
        break
```